# Frequency of oscillator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

We are given an undamped simple harmonic oscillator, and two positions $x_{1}, x_{2}$ with the corresponding velocities $v_{1}, v_{2}$. We want to find its frequency in terms of the $x_{i}$ and $v_{i}$. Since the oscillator is undamped, we can easily find it by conservation of energy, giving a value of 
\begin{equation}\sqrt{\frac{v_{2}^{2} - v_{1}^{2}}{x_{1}^{2} - x_{2}^2}}.\end{equation}
Now, I wanted to find an alternative approach:

By newton's second law, if $k$ is the constant of the oscillator and $m$ its mass, we have that $-kx = m\frac{dv}{dt}$. Since $\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dx}v$, $-kx = mv\frac{dv}{dx}$. 
From here, we can integrate:
\begin{equation}
\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}} -kx\,dx = m\int_{v_{1}}^{v_{2}}v\, dv \\
\frac{-k(x_{2}^{2} - x_{1}^{2})}{2} = m\frac{v_{2}^{2} - v_{1}^{2}}{2} \\
\end{equation}
Now, since $\omega^{2} = \frac{k}{m}$, we get the desired result.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Note that Yes/No has to less characters to be even a comment. Thus it is advisable to restructure your question in order to make your question to a more general public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You second approach is still the conservation of energy, *i.e.* $\frac{1}{2}mv^2 + \frac{1}{2}k x^2$ is a constant for the system. The expression $\int kx dx$ is the work done by the force.